# increment number generated across Distinct values

Tags: sql

I have a Table

```
Apple
Apple
Grape
Grape
Grape
Orange
Orange
Orange
```

I am looking for an output
like

```
1 Apple
2 Grape
3 Orange
```

So it should distinct the values and get an auto incrementing number.

My effort so far is like this.

```
SELECT 
(row_number() over (order by 'Fruit')) AS 'Id' ,
'Fruit'
FROM 
(
SELECT 'Fruit'
 FROM myTable  GROUP BY 'Fruit'
 )  t
```

What is the best way to do this over a large dataset.

Comment: http://rextester.com/MTT67071

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for `dense_rank()`:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by Fruit) as id, Fruit
from mytable;
```

That returns the original rows.

If you just want one row per `fruit`, then select the rows and then use `row_number()`:

```
select fruit, row_number() over (order by fruit)
from (select distinct fruit from mytable) t;
```

Do not use single quotes for column aliases.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I only need on row per fruit. Is distinct faster than the group by.

Comment: @TronaldDump . . . They should be pretty similar performance-wise.  `select distinct` is easier to write.

Comment: Thank you - I got so many  different answers involving partitioning, etc.  This is the first simple answer I found.